# ios - Share image with twitter

Tags: ios, twitter

In order to avoid a discontinued [Twitter Kit](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios) I want to share an Image object using canOpenURL method.

This is my code but is not working.

Is possible share an image only with twitter app?

```
func shareTwitter(image: UIImage, result: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        guard let url = NSURL(string: "twitter://app") else {
            if let result = result {
                result(false)
            }
            return
        }

        let image = image.scaleImageWithAspectToWidth(toWidth: 640)

        do {
            try PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {
                let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)

                let assetID = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset?.localIdentifier ?? ""
                let shareURL = "twitter://post?message=hello%20world&media_id=" + assetID

                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
                    if let urlForRedirect = NSURL(string: shareURL) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(urlForRedirect as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            if let result = result {
                result(false)
            }
        }
    }
```